# VS2012 : File Properties; How to specify a default Custom Tool by file type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, razor, apache-spark

I'm looking for some mechanism to automatically apply values for File Properties (as seen in the VS Properties Window) when adding a new files of particular types into VS2012 projects.

For example, if someone adds a `*.cshtml` file, I'd like the Custom Tool to be set by default to 'RazorGenerator' because it can be a hassle ensuring this is specified manually across all razor files.

Similar again for `*.spark` where the Build Action must always be set to Content (or the CI build breaks).

There doesn't seem to be any VS2012 built in settings for configuring default file properties, so what are people doing to solve this that could work well for a team of developers?

I'm looking for options.

Answer (score 0):

The ANTLR 4 C# target requires similar actions be taken when ***.g4** files which are added to the project.

- Set the **Build Action** to `Antlr4`
- Set several additional properties to default values
- Expose several custom properties via customization of the **Properties** window in Visual Studio

Based on your question, I'll focus on *only the first item*.

### Providing a default build action for a file type

This is actually a feature provided as part of the [ANTLR Language Support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f) extension. The extension performs the operations when a file with particular extensions is added to the project. See the comment at the beginning of `OnAfterAddFilesEx` for details of the behavior. This code is from a class which extends `Package` and implements `IVsTrackProjectDocumentsEvents2`. The implementation of the remaining methods for this interface simply return `VSConstants.E_NOTIMPL`. Note that this code may use custom extension methods that are defined elsewhere within my solution. The code is not intended to be used directly, but merely serve as a guide for someone looking to perform a similar operation via their own extension.

```
private static readonly Guid CSharpProjectTypeGuid = Guid.Parse(PrjKind.prjKindCSharpProject);

private uint _trackDocumentsEventsCookie;

protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();

    IVsTrackProjectDocuments2 trackDocuments2 = serviceProvider.GetTrackProjectDocuments2();
    trackDocuments2.AdviseTrackProjectDocumentsEvents(this, out _trackDocumentsEventsCookie);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (_trackDocumentsEventsCookie != 0)
        {
            var serviceProvider = this.AsVsServiceProvider();
            IVsTrackProjectDocuments2 trackDocuments = serviceProvider.GetTrackProjectDocuments2();
            trackDocuments.UnadviseTrackProjectDocumentsEvents(_trackDocumentsEventsCookie);
            _trackDocumentsEventsCookie = 0;
        }
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

public int OnAfterAddFilesEx(int cProjects, int cFiles, IVsProject[] rgpProjects, int[] rgFirstIndices, string[] rgpszMkDocuments, VSADDFILEFLAGS[] rgFlags)
{
    /* need to make the following alterations:
        *  1. set the Build Action of *.g and *.g3 to Antlr3
        *  2. set the Build Action of *.g4 to Antlr4
        *  3. set the Custom Tool of *.g, *.g3, and *.g4 to MSBuild:Compile
        *  4. set the Custom Tool Namespace of *.g4 to $(RootNamespace) + relative folder path
        */

    for (int i = 0; i < cProjects; i++)
    {
        IVsProject project = rgpProjects[i];
        int projectFiles = (i == cProjects - 1) ? cFiles : rgFirstIndices[i + 1];
        projectFiles -= rgFirstIndices[i];

        if (!IsCSharpProject(project))
            continue;

        for (int j = 0; j < projectFiles; j++)
        {
            string currentFile = rgpszMkDocuments[rgFirstIndices[i] + j];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentFile))
                continue;

            bool grammarFile =
                currentFile.EndsWith(".tokens", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || currentFile.EndsWith(".g", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || currentFile.EndsWith(".g3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || currentFile.EndsWith(".g4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            if (grammarFile)
            {
                OnAfterAddedGrammarFile(project, currentFile);
            }
        }
    }

    return VSConstants.S_OK;
}

private static bool IsCSharpProject(IVsProject project)
{
    IVsAggregatableProject aggregatableProject = project as IVsAggregatableProject;
    if (aggregatableProject == null)
        return false;

    string guidsString = null;
    if (ErrorHandler.Failed(ErrorHandler.CallWithCOMConvention(() => aggregatableProject.GetAggregateProjectTypeGuids(out guidsString))))
        return false;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(guidsString))
        return false;

    string[] guids = guidsString.Split(';');
    foreach (var guidString in guids)
    {
        Guid guid;
        if (Guid.TryParse(guidString, out guid) && guid == CSharpProjectTypeGuid)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private void OnAfterAddedGrammarFile(IVsProject project, string currentFile)
{
    int found;
    VSDOCUMENTPRIORITY[] priority = new VSDOCUMENTPRIORITY[1];
    uint itemId;
    if (ErrorHandler.Failed(project.IsDocumentInProject(currentFile, out found, priority, out itemId)))
        return;

    if (found == 0 || priority[0] != VSDOCUMENTPRIORITY.DP_Standard)
        return;

    string desiredItemType = "Antlr3";
    if (string.Equals(Path.GetExtension(currentFile), ".tokens", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        desiredItemType = "AntlrTokens";
    else if (string.Equals(Path.GetExtension(currentFile), ".g4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        desiredItemType = "Antlr4";

    IVsHierarchy hierarchy = project as IVsHierarchy;
    if (hierarchy != null)
    {
        object browseObject = null;
        PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptors = null;
        int hr = ErrorHandler.CallWithCOMConvention(() => hierarchy.GetProperty(itemId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_BrowseObject, out browseObject));
        if (ErrorHandler.Succeeded(hr))
            propertyDescriptors = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(browseObject);

        object obj;
        hr = hierarchy.GetProperty(itemId, (int)__VSHPROPID4.VSHPROPID_BuildAction, out obj);
        if (ErrorHandler.Succeeded(hr))
        {
            string buildAction = obj != null ? obj.ToString() : null;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(buildAction) || string.Equals(buildAction, "None", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                hr = ErrorHandler.CallWithCOMConvention(() => hierarchy.SetProperty(itemId, (int)__VSHPROPID4.VSHPROPID_BuildAction, desiredItemType));
            }
        }

        if (ErrorHandler.Failed(hr) && propertyDescriptors != null)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor itemTypeDescriptor = propertyDescriptors["ItemType"] ?? propertyDescriptors["BuildAction"];
            if (itemTypeDescriptor != null)
            {
                obj = itemTypeDescriptor.GetValue(browseObject);
                string buildAction = (string)itemTypeDescriptor.Converter.ConvertToInvariantString(obj);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(buildAction) || string.Equals(buildAction, "None", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        obj = itemTypeDescriptor.Converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(desiredItemType);
                        itemTypeDescriptor.SetValue(browseObject, obj);
                    }
                    catch (NotSupportedException)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (propertyDescriptors != null)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor customToolDescriptor = propertyDescriptors["CustomTool"];
            if (customToolDescriptor != null)
            {
                obj = customToolDescriptor.GetValue(browseObject);
                string customTool = customToolDescriptor.Converter.ConvertToInvariantString(obj);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customTool))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        obj = customToolDescriptor.Converter.ConvertToInvariantString("MSBuild:Compile");
                        customToolDescriptor.SetValue(browseObject, obj);
                    }
                    catch (NotSupportedException)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }

            PropertyDescriptor customToolNamespaceDescriptor = propertyDescriptors["CustomToolNamespace"];
            if (customToolNamespaceDescriptor != null)
            {
                object defaultNamespace;
                hr = hierarchy.GetProperty(itemId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_DefaultNamespace, out defaultNamespace);
                if (ErrorHandler.Succeeded(hr) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultNamespace as string))
                {
                    obj = customToolNamespaceDescriptor.GetValue(browseObject);
                    string customToolNamespace = customToolNamespaceDescriptor.Converter.ConvertToInvariantString(obj);
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customToolNamespace))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            obj = customToolNamespaceDescriptor.Converter.ConvertToInvariantString(defaultNamespace);
                            customToolNamespaceDescriptor.SetValue(browseObject, obj);
                        }
                        catch (NotSupportedException)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach and I may have to try it, is there no simpler way?